# 404 error while trying to call asp.net web api using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I tried creating a simple asp.net web api and tried calling it using jQuery. But it throws a 404 error.
Here is the web api code

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public Product GetProductDetail()
    {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.ProductName = "Cricket Bat";
        product.ProductPrice = "100";

        return product;
    }
}
```

And here is the jQuery Ajax code:

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Controllers/ProductController/GetProductDetail',
            success: function (success) {
                console.log(success);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: change type: 'GET' to type: 'POST' in $.ajax() function and replace "Controllers/ProductController/GetProductDetail" by "/Product/GetProductDetail" and it would be better if you will use [HttpGet] for getting data

Comment: tried both `GET` and `POST` but both not working...

Comment: @SergeyBoiko still not working. Throwing error `POST http://localhost:49826/Product/GetProductDetail 404 (Not Found) ` in console

Comment: could you please show your routes?

Comment: @SergeyBoiko thnks man. The key was hidden dere :) route was `api/Product/GetProductDetail` . sins of being a new bie ;)

Comment: it's nice to hear that all works :)

Comment: Question for you, why have you called the method `GetProductDetail` when it is a Post? When using WebApi, it should be a RESTful service which means that your method should be called `Post` and your URL should just be `/Api/Product`

Comment: Sins of being a newbie to web api I guess. I'm trying to figure out things. Thnks for the pointers :)

Comment: regarding to @ Tim B James question, @iJay, if you are just playing with API - it's ok :) but in real world it's wrong - as you need use PUT, POST, UPDATE etc. with urls like: /api/product or /api/product/5

Comment: but just out of curiosity ..why is it wrong @SergeyBoiko

Comment: don't know why someone has given you a -1, so +1 to balance it out. It isn't "wrong" but just not following standard design patterns. If you are not following a RESTful design pattern, then you would might as well just use a WebService

Comment: @TimBJames sounds fair enough

Comment: @iJay, as mentioned by @ Tim B James, in ASP.NET Web API you have to use RESTful style, you cannot just write any action and call this. There many articles in the web that you can read about how to properly create RESTful web service

Answer (score 0):

Try decorating your method with HttpGet from System.Web.Http and Not System.Web.Mvc

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public Product GetProductDetail()
   {
       Product product = new Product();
       product.ProductName = "Cricket Bat";
       product.ProductPrice = "100";

       return product;
   }
}
```

Then change your ajax url to "/Product/GetProductDetail"